# Parsing data fram to add new column and update the column pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, pyspark

I have the below code that creates a data frame as below :

```
ratings = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("myfile.json").map(lambda l: json.loads(l)),
)



ratings.registerTempTable("mytable")

final_df = sqlContext.sql("select * from mytable");
```

[The data frame look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDZvN.png)

I'm storing the `created_at` and `user_id` into a list :

```
user_id_list = final_df.select('user_id').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
created_at_list = final_df.select('created_at').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

and parsing through one of the list to call another function:

```
for i in range(len(user_id_list)):
    status=get_status(user_id_list[I],created_at_list[I])
```

I want to create a new column in my data frame called status and update the value for the corresponding `user_id_list` and `created_at_list value`

I know I need use this functionality - but not sure how to proceed

```
final_df.withColumn('status', 'give the condition here')
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont create lists. Simply give a UDF function to dataframe

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
status_udf = F.udf(lambda x: get_status(x[0], x[1]))
df = df.select(df.columns + [status_udf(F.col('user_id_list'), \
               F.col('created_at_list value')).alias('status')])
```